# Migrating to swift 3 and faced with segmentation fault 11 errors

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Wondering if anyone has any advice for me on this matter. Trying to migrate my project to Swift 3.0. I am now getting the dreaded ***Segmentation fault 11 error***. I had this previously and noticed in the error messages it was because I still had `Firebase` in my pods which hasn't yet been updated for Swift 3. I removed the pod and the issue resolved itself. Now there seems to be a new error that appears when I fix this line:

```
var phoneDisabled = false//AppDependencies.firebaseConfig.configValue(forKey: "RegisterPhoneDisabledKey").boolValue // Seg error?
```

As you can see I need to comment out the `Firebase` code so for now I just want to swap it out with `false`. Now I am getting the Segmentation error. I'm pretty sure it's not actually related to this line at all, it just depends where the compiler is at and if I had edited files in a different order then it would have appeared elsewhere. Either way I get to a point where I'm stuck in this segmentation fault error.

[image]

I can fix all the error in this buildtime pane ^ but eventually I'm just stuck on this. It seems to list the same 4 files each time:

[image]

Code dump from the first one:

```
CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/MyApp/CancelQuestionWorker.swift
    cd /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -filelist /var/folders/wb/9dsv1b5j53n8qbwmbh49qf9m0000gn/T/sources-a0ba4d -primary-file "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/MyApp/CancelQuestionWorker.swift" -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk -I /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AMPopTip -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireImage -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireObjectMapper -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bolts -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Branch -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DKVerticalColorPicker -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EDStarRating -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQMessagesViewController -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQSystemSoundPlayer -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Jukebox -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MIBadgeButton -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MZTimerLabel -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mixpanel -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapper -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PubNub -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QueryKit -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReachabilitySwift -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SZTextView -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftDate -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TCCopyableLabel -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TOCropViewController -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TTTAttributedLabel -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS" -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Fabric/iOS" -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Intercom/Intercom" -F "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app" -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header "/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/MyApp/Obj-C-bridge.h" -module-cache-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D COCOAPODS -D DEV -D DEBUG -D TARGET_IOS_SIMULATOR -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/swift-overrides.hmap" -Xcc -iquote -Xcc "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-generated-files.hmap" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-own-target-headers.hmap" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap" -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-project-headers.hmap" -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Crashlytics" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Fabric" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleAnalytics" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleIDFASupport" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleTagManager" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Intercom" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/DerivedSources/x86_64" -Xcc "-I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/DerivedSources" -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc "-working-directory/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app" -emit-module-doc-path "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancelQuestionWorker~partial.swiftdoc" -Onone -module-name SA_Dev -emit-module-path "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancelQuestionWorker~partial.swiftmodule" -serialize-diagnostics-path "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancelQuestionWorker.dia" -emit-dependencies-path "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancelQuestionWorker.d" -emit-reference-dependencies-path "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancelQuestionWorker.swiftdeps" -o "/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancelQuestionWorker.o"

0  swift                    0x00000001098f4b6d PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 45
1  swift                    0x00000001098f45b6 SignalHandler(int) + 470
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8edb152a _sigtramp + 26
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x000000010e99d160 _sigtramp + 2143206480
4  swift                    0x0000000107587865 (anonymous namespace)::DeclChecker::checkOverrides(swift::TypeChecker&, swift::ValueDecl*) + 5749
5  swift                    0x000000010757795e swift::TypeChecker::validateDecl(swift::ValueDecl*, bool) + 3150
6  swift                    0x00000001075926a5 (anonymous namespace)::DeclChecker::visitFuncDecl(swift::FuncDecl*) + 4453
7  swift                    0x000000010757c112 (anonymous namespace)::DeclChecker::visit(swift::Decl*) + 3282
8  swift                    0x00000001075772e7 swift::TypeChecker::validateDecl(swift::ValueDecl*, bool) + 1495
9  swift                    0x000000010757790a swift::TypeChecker::validateDecl(swift::ValueDecl*, bool) + 3066
10 swift                    0x00000001075a49db swift::performTypeChecking(swift::SourceFile&, swift::TopLevelContext&, swift::OptionSet<swift::TypeCheckingFlags, unsigned int>, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 7627
11 swift                    0x0000000107259aab swift::CompilerInstance::performSema() + 5643
12 swift                    0x0000000106d0600d performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 2765
13 swift                    0x0000000106d03265 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 17029
14 swift                    0x0000000106cc082d main + 8685
15 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff82f885ad start + 1
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -filelist /var/folders/wb/9dsv1b5j53n8qbwmbh49qf9m0000gn/T/sources-a0ba4d -primary-file /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/MyApp/CancelQuestionWorker.swift -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk -I /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AMPopTip -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireImage -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireObjectMapper -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bolts -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Branch -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DKVerticalColorPicker -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EDStarRating -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQMessagesViewController -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQSystemSoundPlayer -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Jukebox -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MIBadgeButton -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MZTimerLabel -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mixpanel -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ObjectMapper -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PubNub -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QueryKit -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReachabilitySwift -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SZTextView -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftDate -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TCCopyableLabel -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TOCropViewController -F /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TTTAttributedLabel -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Fabric/iOS -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Intercom/Intercom -F /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/MyApp/Obj-C-bridge.h -module-cache-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D COCOAPODS -D DEV -D DEBUG -D TARGET_IOS_SIMULATOR -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/SA Dev-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Crashlytics -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Fabric -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleAnalytics -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleIDFASupport -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleTagManager -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app/Pods/Headers/Public/Intercom -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/kekearif/Documents/MyApp/MyApp Dev/ios-app -emit-module-doc-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancelQuestionWorker~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name SA_Dev -emit-module-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancelQuestionWorker~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancelQuestionWorker.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancelQuestionWorker.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancelQuestionWorker.swiftdeps -o /Users/kekearif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dsxatbasknspfhezcnukgtimgkqf/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp DEV.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CancelQuestionWorker.o 
1.  While type-checking getter for frame at <invalid loc>
```

The other three are very similar (let me know if you need to see them). I know that the files listed don't have any errors in them and have also tried copying the code to a clean project with no issues. I'm not sure why these files are listed. As this is a migrate, nearly every single file needs some changes made. Maybe one approach would be to ignore this error and edit the files one by one. However Xcode isn't highlighting errors in other files at all or is only highlighting a few intermittently. Seems to have reduced functionality when stuck on this error. I've checked the pods are correct. I've done a clean install on the pods. I've cleared XCODE's derived data and done a project clean. No help. What should I do? Does anyone have any experience with this? Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Banging my head against a wall on this one.

Comment: try to clear derived data folder of your app. @Kex

Comment: @KAR, tried this. Same error.